# How to match user name and password using FormsAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, forms-authentication

**C#**

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(txtName.ToString(),txtPass.ToString()))
        {
             Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");
        }
         else
        {
            Response.Redirect("user.aspx");
        }
    }
```

**Config:**

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
 <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" > 
  <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1"> 
  <user name="mohit" password="mohit"/> 
  </credentials> 
 </forms> 
</authentication>
```

Its not redirecting to admin page. Whenever I login else condtion works.

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" >
        <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
          <user name="mohit" password="mohit"/>
        </credentials>
      </forms>
      
    </authentication>

Comment: At least you should mention what is wrong my friend

Comment: its not redirecting to admin page. whenever i login else condtion works

Answer (score 0):

Try like this instead:

```
    if(FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(txtName.Text, txtPass.Text))
    {
         Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("user.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: i know this but tha not the solution its not working

Comment: Your question isnt very clear, what are `txtName` and `textPass`

Comment: your password value should be hashed using SHA1, so it should look like that: `<user name="mohit" password="9944BB848BBSDS"/>`

Answer (score 0):

// Set the *passwordFormat="SHA1"* to  **passwordFormat="Clear"** in credentials tag

```
 <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl ="Default.aspx" DefaultUrl="~/admin.aspx">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
          <user name="mohit" password="mohit"/> 
        </credentials>
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users ="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

It's Working to me.

Answer (score 0):

Change the PasswordFormat to Clear (i.e., passwordFormat="Clear"), because when you mention `Password format` to SHA1 (it is an algorithm), forms authentication will never compare a plain text password with `algorithm` of `type` 98ahcnd15. Use authorization tag in web.config file under <system.web>.